# Sencha Touch List/Store Won't Contact Server

Tags: sencha-touch

I'm attempting to put together a Sencha Touch 2 front end to go with a Rails back end (that returns JSON). However, I've found that running the following script doesn't contact the server at all. I'm sure there is a very simple solution to this problem!  If I add the line: `autoLoad: true` to my Store, then the server IS contacted, but I see a never ending loading image in my browser.

Thanks VERY much for helping out! Please lemme know if there's any more info you'd like to see.

--Jared

**index.js**

```
ListDemo = new Ext.Application({

name: "ListDemo",

launch: function() {

    ListDemo.listPanel = new Ext.List({
        id: 'disclosurelist',
        store: ListDemo.ListStore,
        itemTpl: '<div class="contact">{title}</div>',
        onItemDisclosure: function(record, btn, index) {
            ListDemo.detailPanel.update(record.data);
            ListDemo.Viewport.setActiveItem('detailpanel');
        }
    });

    ListDemo.Viewport = new Ext.Panel ({
        fullscreen: true,
        layout: 'card',
        cardSwitchAnimation: 'slide',
        items: [ListDemo.listPanel]
    });

}
});
```

**data.js**

```
Ext.regModel('Article', {
        fields: [
            {name: 'title',       type: 'string'},
                    {name: 'url',     type: 'string'}
        ],
        proxy: {
          type: 'rest',
          url : 'articles',
            format: 'json',
          reader: {
              type: 'json',
              root: 'articles',
                record: 'entry'
          }
      }
});

ListDemo.ListStore = new Ext.data.Store({
        model: 'Article'
})
```

Here's what the server responds with if I visit localhost:3000/articles.json:

```
{"articles":
    [
        {"created_at":"2012-07-18T23:54:08Z","from":null,"id":1,"image":"","title":"Inquiry Seeks Accomplices of Bomber in Bulgaria","updated_at":"2012-07-21T06:13:54Z","url":"www.newyorktimes.com"},
        {"created_at":"2012-07-19T00:01:35Z","from":null,"id":2,"image":"","title":"Changing Harlem Celebrates Queen of Soul Food","updated_at":"2012-07-21T06:26:13Z","url":"www.newyorktimes.com/harlem"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console ?

Comment: @TDeBailleul I see the following:

WARN  Could not determine content-length of response body. Set content-length of the response or set Response#chunked = true

Comment: @TDeBailleul HOWEVER, I know that the action at the /articles URL is not executing because it's set up with a puts statement to verify its execution

Answer (score 0):

Your server script should return JSON that looks like this:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "articles": [
        {"created_at":"2012-07-18T23:54:08Z","from":null,"id":1,"image":"","title":"Inquiry Seeks Accomplices of Bomber in Bulgaria","updated_at":"2012-07-21T06:13:54Z","url":"www.newyorktimes.com"},
        {"created_at":"2012-07-19T00:01:35Z","from":null,"id":2,"image":"","title":"Changing Harlem Celebrates Queen of Soul Food","updated_at":"2012-07-21T06:26:13Z","url":"www.newyorktimes.com/harlem"}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thx for your response, @Tinashe!  However, it seems to make no difference in the way sencha behaves. Can you see anything wrong with my index.js or data.js?